# Dynamic Programming +Bit-Masks

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, bitmask

I recently learned the concept of Bit Manipulation for **Competitive Programming** so I'm quite new to the concept ,I also read many tutorials on **Bit-Masking + Dynamic Programming**  on Hackerearth ,CodeChef  and many more .

I also solved a couple of problems on Codechef including this one [problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MARCHA1)
and I have a couple of doubts regarding Bitmasks after I have been through some questions.

The problems I solved were mostly focused on manipulating the *subsets* but I wonder how do I work on **permutations** with bitmasks , i.e when I have to work on a state where all bits in the mask need to be set.

For ex: If we have to find number of numbers that can be formed by arranging all digits of a given number A which are divisible by a given number B  where (A ,B<= 10**6) how can this be done with bitmasks.(I hope this can be done with bitmask+dp)

If A= 514 ,and B=2
The question expects the answer to be

514

154

Which are  both divisible by 2 .

So the answer is 2.
  With the knowledge I have: 514 and 154 represent the same mask *111* where all bits are *set* So how do I use bitmasks here where the mask is same for two or more answers!( I hope you understand this ).

And also as it is impossible to allocate memory worth n!*n for a little large value of n since we can have that many permutations of digits how can this problem be done using bitmasks where we need only (2**n)*n  space (If i'm not wrong).

So how do I approach the above problem iteratively? /Or any DP state equation which I can possibly understand ,I couldn't understand recursive approach of some similar problems I Read.

I also tried to think on a similar problem [TSHIRTS](https://www.codechef.com/AUG14/problems/TSHIRTS) but I couldn't understand the logic behind the recursion.

Comment: There is a special site for puzzles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need DP for this one but you can use bit manipulation nicely :) Since A <= 10^6 it means that A has most 7 digits; so you only have to check 7! = 5040 states.

```
const int A = 514;
const int B = 2;
vector <int> v; //contains digits of A (e.g. 5, 1, 4) this can be done before the recursive function in a while loop.

int rec(int mask, int current_number){
    if(mask == (1 << v.size()) - 1){ //no digit left to pick
        if(current_number % B == 0) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    int ret = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        if(mask & (1 << i)) continue; //this is already picked
        ret += rec(mask | (1 << i), current_number * 10 + v[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Note that the reason I didn't use DP here was that current number might differ even if mask is the same; so you can't actually say that the situation has been repeated. Unless you memo-ize mask **AND** current_number which requires much more space.